# i am having a problem with pygmo software

Tags: python, optimization, conda, particle-swarm, pygmo

i have installed the pygmo software via conda prompt. and while running . the following error appeared. how can i fix my installation

````
<ipython-input-10-3786d79ff26a> in <module>
----> 1 from pygmo import *
      2 from pygmo import *
      3 import numpy as np
      4 pop_size=200
      5 problems=[1,2]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygmo\__init__.py in <module>
     11 from ._version import __version__
     12 # We import the sub-modules into the root namespace
---> 13 from .core import *
     14 from .core import _pagmo_version_major, _pagmo_version_minor, _pagmo_version_patch
     15 from .plotting import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.```
````